# Is it possible to flush a node response to the client to keep a connection alive?

Tags: node.js, express, http, response, http-streaming

I have a large data-set that a client is requesting. It requires loading and processing so I can convert it to CSV. If I try to load and convert the entire data-set at once it doesn't finish processing before the client times out. In response to this, I load my data-set and then chunk it for processing. At this point I have data ready to send to the client *before* the timeout.

My issue is that when I send the data, either by piping my write stream into the response, or by listening to my write stream and sending VIA `response.write`, it does not get sent in time. This seems to be because I'm not hitting the highWaterMark on the response writer. I need a way to either tell the connection to wait longer (`res.setTimeout(2147483647);` doesn't seem to do the trick), lower the `highWaterMark`, or to drain the response so the client consistently gets the processed data as it comes in.

This is on Node 12.x w/ Express 4.

Comment: I don't see any obvious way to flush an httpResponse stream in node.js to get it to send out anything that is buffered.  In node.js v13.2.0+, you could try calling `res.cork()`, write a little data and then call `res.uncork()` and see if that accomplishes it, but that was only added in this newer version.

Comment: It looks like Node v12.16.0 has support for response cork/uncork. I got things to work by corking/uncorking every time I wrote data. I'm going to call this solved.

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to flush a node response to the client to keep a connection alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217161/is-it-possible-to-flush-a-node-response-to-the-client-to-keep-a-connection-alive#comment106512593_60217161)
As per what jfriend00 said, corking my response before writing data, writing the data, and then uncorking it caused it to be sent to the client.

Calling this solved.